# Will my Wizz Discount Club membership renew automatically?

Tags: wizz-air, payment

I just subscribed to Wizz Air's Discount Club to save some money on fares. Normally, whenever I begin any kind of paid subscription, I instantly unsubscribe to avoid being charged again on an unwanted renewal.

However, looking at the Terms and Conditions, "unsubscribing" seems to cancel one's membership...

> [1.3. A Member may cancel his or her membership in the Club at any time by selecting the unsubscribe option on My Profile page](http://corporate.wizzair.com/en-GB/travel_services/WECTermsandC)

...and I didn't see anything in the terms about automatic renewal.

That said, knowing low-cost airlines' business practices, I just want to make doubly sure I'm taking the right course of action (by *not* unsubscribing), leading me to these two questions:

1) **Will "unsubscribing" from the Wizz Air Discount Club cancel the remainder of my subscription?**

2) **If I don't unsubscribe, will my membership automatically renew?**

Comment: Downvoter: if you explain your motivation, I can update the question accordingly. Thanks!

Comment: Even though I included a citation from the t&c in the question? Restrain your trigger finger...

Answer (score 10, accepted):

> If I don't unsubscribe, will my membership automatically renew?

According to Wizzair's [official Twitter](https://twitter.com/wizzair), you have to renew it manually:

[image]

> Will "unsubscribing" from the Wizz Air Discount Club cancel the remainder of my subscription?

Their updated website no longer has the option to unsubscribe from Discount Club membership, so the question is moot.