# Are there any disadvantages of Wizz Discount Club?

Tags: budget, wizz-air

I can't find any sensible reason not to buy Wizz Discount Club, but they must make money somehow. Do you know why do they have it at all?

I thought it auto-renews automatically next year, but [no](https://travel.stackexchange.com/questions/83410/will-my-wizz-discount-club-membership-renew-automatically).
Perhaps the discounts get much worse once you buy it, but the first return trip for 2 people with luggage already enough to pay for the membership + get some money back.

I speculate

1. The membership motivates people to travel with WizzAir more. They make money on other things during this travel.
2. The membership enforces one to use their real account each time, so they can track better and perhaps optimize their prices higher.

But I have no confidence.

Comment: You are flying with wizz. thats a disadvantage.

Comment: Cost/benefit. It costs a certain amount to get the membership, and then it takes a certain number of flights to have your savings exceed the cost of membership. So you will either be encouraged to fly more with this company, increasing profit due to increased purchases/flights, or you will fly the same amount and they will get the profit from your membership. It probably also comes with extra marketing and upselling opportunities for them too.

Comment: It probably lets them segment business travelers thus charging them more, since most won't bother with a club, and it may be difficult to get reimbursed for one.

Comment: @RoddyoftheFrozenPeas, often 1 flight is already enough to save more than the cost of membership.

Comment: @FlyingWell this is actually quite rare, and I only seen it happening on the competitive routes which many airlines fly. Compare the WizzClub price vs Ryanair/Eurowings/Norwegian.

Answer (score 3):

I think the main reason is to make you use their services more frequently. A lot of the time the price for WizzAir and another carrier differs not so much, so if you have the Discount Club, you are more likely to buy new tickets with them.

As I see, they earn the most money from selling additional features such as priority boarding or luggage. If you discount for the ticket, you will more likely choose the WizzAir and more likely will buy something extra.